# Uniform convergence of the harmonic form heat flow

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

[${\bf NOTATIONS}$]

Let $M$ be a closed Riemannian manifold of $m$ dimensional, $p\in\{1,\cdots,m\}$. 
$A^p:=\{\text{smooth p-forms on }M\}$. $\delta:A^{p+1}\to A^p$ denotes the formally adjoint operator w.r.t. the $L^2$-metric on $A^p$ ,that is,
\begin{eqnarray}
\delta\alpha:=g^{ij}\iota\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}\right)\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}}\alpha
\end{eqnarray}
, which satisfies
\begin{eqnarray}
\langle d\alpha, \beta\rangle_{L^2}+\langle\alpha, \delta\beta\rangle_{L^2}=0\ \ \ (\alpha\in A^p, \beta\in A^{p+1}). 
\end{eqnarray}
We define $\Delta\alpha:=d\delta\alpha+\delta d\alpha\ \ \ (\alpha\in A^p)$.

Let $\alpha\in A^p$. We accept the fact that there is an unique smooth solution $\beta:[0,\infty)\to A^p$ of the equation
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial\beta}{\partial t}(t)=\Delta\beta(t)\ \ \ (t\geq0)\\
\beta(0)=\alpha. 
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Then for each $t\geq0$ we can define a linear operator $T_t(=e^{t\Delta}):A^p\to A^p$ by
\begin{eqnarray}
T_t\alpha:=\beta(t). 
\end{eqnarray}

Since $\dfrac{d}{dt}||\beta(t)||_{L^2}^2\leq0$, $||T_t||\leq1$ therefore $T_t$ extends continuously to $T_t:L^2A^p\to L^2A^p$, where $L^2A^p:=\{\text{measurable p-forms on }M\text{ whose norms belong to }L^2(M)\}$.

[${\bf PROPERTIES}$]
I was able to follow the proofs of the following properties:

> $T_t\circ T_s=T_{s+t}\ \ \ (s,t\geq0)$.
>   $T_t$ is symmetric i.e.  $\langle\alpha_1, T_t\alpha_2\rangle_{L^2}=\langle T_t\alpha_1,\alpha_2\rangle_{L^2}$.
>
> $\exists H\alpha\in A^p\ \ \ T_t\alpha\to H\alpha$ in $L^2(M)$.

[${\bf QUESTION}$]

I'm reading Milgram and Rosenbloom *Harmonic Forms and Heat Conduction*

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1063329/?page=1

. Let $\alpha\in A^p$ be a closed form. I need to show the property that

> there exists a sequence $(t_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ s.t. $\lim t_n=\infty$ and $T_{t_n}\alpha\to H\alpha$ uniformly on $M$.

But I cannot understand the explanation in the paper below. Please help me. Thank you. 
[image: M-R]

Comment: It is enough to show the boundedness of the solution $\beta$ in $M\times[1,\infty)$. Are there any estimates of such kind?